# Is there a way to get the statistics of a datasource through the Amazon ML API?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-machine-learning, aws-sdk-net

Looking through the datasource methods in the Machine Learning API (specifically the .Net API), I'm unable to find where I can retrieve the statistics that are computed from a datasource when ComputeStatistics=true.  Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

This is apparently not supported.  Source https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=738296&#738296